# Incremental increase of a variable over time

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am usually programming in Python, but for an assignment, I am using Simulink. I am wondering why the above `elseif` ladder does not generate an incremental increase of the variable [IP3] over time. What I would think it should do is return 0.01 until t = 500, then 0.03 until t = 1000, then 0.1 until 1500, 1 until 2000, and 10 from then on. Apologies for the older image btw, I updated the variables in the mean time.

[image: Incremental increase of variable over time]

Comment: Seems like it would have been simpler to design it with [step functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/step.html) and a [max](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/minmax.html) block.

Answer (score 1):

In the Simulink model that you showed, `elseif` parts will never execute since:

- if `u1>0` is satisfied, none of the other conditions will be checked and thus it will always be returning `0.01` for all `u1>0`.
- And when `u1<=0`, all the conditions will be checked but none of them
  will be satisfied. (`u1` may never be less than zero in your case as `u1` is time).

This behavior is same in every programming language.

---

**Fixing your `If-elseif` Statements:**

You need to add this in the [`If` block](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/if.html):

1. Under `If expression (e.g. u1 ~= 0)`, write this:

   ```
   u1>0 & u1<=500
   ```
2. Under `Elseif expressions (comma-separated list, e.g. u2 ~= 0, u3(2) < u2):`, write this:

   ```
   u1>500 & u1<=1000, u1>1000 & u1<=1500, u1>1500 & u1<=2000, u1>2000
   ```

---

Since `u1` is time in your case which cannot be negative, you may also want to use the `else` part. So instead of the last step you can also do this:

Under `Elseif expressions (comma-separated list, e.g. u2 ~= 0, u3(2) < u2):`, write this:

```
u1>500 & u1<=1000, u1>1000 & u1<=1500, u1>1500 & u1<=2000
```

and connect the output of the `else` part which was connected with the output of `u1>2000` before.